# Finding ways to get free radar (SAR) satellite imagery data sets

Tags: data, image, satellite, radar, sentinel-1

I am looking for finding ways to obtain free (non-commercial use) sources of synthetic aperture radar (SAR) satellite imagery. Does anyone know of sources?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- You can get Sentinel-1 data from [scihub.esa](https://scihub.esa.int/). Requires only
  registration (And most likely, non-commercial use).  As Sentinel-1
  has just become operational the archive is not very extensive but
  should grow quite quickly.
- You can set request data-access propospal on [Alaska Satellite
  Facility](https://www.asf.alaska.edu/get-data/get-started/). Some data open access. For ALOS-PALSAR you must be a resident of the United States to receive approval for data access.
- You can get data from [UNAVCO](http://www.unavco.org/data/imaging/sar-data/sar-data.html) SAR data archive.
- And you can get data from [earth.esa.int](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/data-access/browse-data-products). To access the data, you must provide a project. To preview scenes, use [EOLi esa](http://earth.esa.int/EOLi/EOLi.html). ENVISAT ASAR the best option.

Answer (score 6):

Only managed to find a couple of sources for SAR images and data:

- You can download SAR images from [**here**](http://webmap.ornl.gov/wcsdown/dataset.jsp?ds_id=993) which are mostly focused on ecological sites such as forests:

[image: Example SAR image]

- You can download SAR samples from [**here**](http://topex.ucsd.edu/gmtsar/downloads/) which contain fairly large datasets (note: the last 4 links at the bottom of the SAR section are dead)

Answer (score 6):

JAXA have made global L-band SAR mosaics at 25 m spatial resolution available from the PALSAR sensor:

http://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/ALOS/en/palsar_fnf/fnf_index.htm

Registration is required to download the data.

Answer (score 6):

Sentinel-1 data is published as Open Data, with attribution, see licence [here](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/twiki/do/view/SciHubWebPortal/TermsConditions).  Registration required. An API is provided. See [Scientific Data Hub](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/) for details.
Software is also provided to process data.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fuller answer about the synthetic aperture radar (SAR) data available from the Alaska Satellite Facility at no cost to users. The datasets include Seasat (1978 data newly processed in 2013), InSAR, **PALSAR (including radiometrically terrain-corrected products)**, RADARSAT-1, ERS-1, ERS-2, JERS-1, UAVSAR, AirMOSS, AirSAR,  and more.

SMAP data will become available in spring or summer 2015.

ASF's Get Started page, at https://www.asf.alaska.edu/get-data/get-started/, has a handy At-a-Glance Guide to Accessing Datasets.