# How to get multi-temporal InSAR data?

Tags: data, remote-sensing, insar

I am very much new to InSAR data. At the moment, i'm stuck at this website https://ursa.asfdaac.alaska.edu. Just wanna know, is it possible to get multi-temporal InSAR data for a particular region from this site or from any other sources. Will be OK even if it's a paid service.

Comment: What do you mean with InSAR data? Do you look for already processed data or Single look complex (SLC)? What time-period do you need? What's your region? Did you check the ESA missions https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/missions/esa-operational-eo-missions? They provide the data for free and they are multitemporal. Or TerraSAR-X, Radarsat, Cosmo-skymed?

Comment: @Iris InSAR - Interferometric Synthetic Aperture Radar. I think we, the user have to process these kind of data by merging two SAR images. I am very much new to this and still couldn't able to figure it out. Wanna know if there is any site providing such processed data. Our study region will be Chennai (South India), area will be around 250 Sq.Km. We are looking for data from 1980's to till date. This pdf has shed some light http://www.esa.int/esapub/tm/tm19/TM-19_ptA.pdf

Comment: Completely processed InSAR data are for example a DEM (e.g. The SRTM DEM).  I would try ERS data first https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/missions/esa-operational-eo-missions/ers. A free software is for the processing example: https://earth.esa.int/web/nest/home

Answer (score 2):

One group of researchers wants to make a map of global displacements in real-time using the Sentinel-1 and GAMMA software (it's commercial software). First results -
[LiCS Portal](http://comet.nerc.ac.uk/COMET-LiCS-portal/)

Also see this [SBAS-DInSAR processing on the GEP](https://discuss.terradue.com/t/workshop-eth-zurich-on-25-01-2017-sbas-dinsar-processing-on-the-gep/118)

The two images will not give you a lot of information (search SBAS and PSI algorithms), but the good news is you can do the processing now.

See this about SLC data: [Free radar (SAR) satellite data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118088/free-radar-sar-satellite-data/118102#118102)

- You can process it himself now use -
  [GMT5SAR](http://topex.ucsd.edu/gmtsar/) can process Sentinel-1, ALOS-2 and etc. GMT5SAR support
  SBAS time-series method. Sentinel-1 already has huge SLC archives worldwide and for India sure and data are available for all [Sentinel-1 data hub](https://scihub.copernicus.eu). Manuals - [UNVACO Course](https://www.unavco.org/education/advancing-geodetic-skills/short-courses/2016/insar-gmtsar/insar-gmtsar.html) and [Forum](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/projects/gmt5sar/boards/6). Just keep in mind the high vegetation (also snow) can cause low coherence especially in India but you will still be able to get acceptable results. Explore these questions in various papers, etc.

> GMTSAR is an open source (GNU General Public License) InSAR processing
>   system designed for users familiar with Generic Mapping Tools (GMT).
>   The code is written in C and will compile on any computer where GMT
>   and NETCDF are installed.
>   Source: [topex.ucsd.edu](http://topex.ucsd.edu/gmtsar/)

- Also you can use (need registration) ROI_PAC and process ALOS-PALSAR 1 (2006-2011) from ASF https://ursa.asfdaac.alaska.edu/cgi-bin/login/guest/ and  https://ursa.asf.alaska.edu/cgi-bin/login/guest/ or vertext tool there are many  stacks of images around world
- Others software - ISCE, StaMPS. (StaMPS free, ISCE need approval)
- Also you can use G-POD Cloud for processing ENVISAT ASAR use P-SBAS algorithm. [G-POD ESA](http://gpod.eo.esa.int). ENVISAT ASAR is freely available

As the processing time-series maps (for example if you want to make a map for the whole of India use Sentinel-1, it's take a lot of time if you use only one processor) requires a significant amount of computing resources, you can use (but for this you need to provide a project and etc) [RSS Cloudtoolbox](http://eogrid.esrin.esa.int/cloudtoolbox/) or G-POD for ENVISAT ASAR use SBAS algorithm (but ENVISAT ASAR have small data for India). More info [RSS Cloudtoolbox](http://wiki.services.eoportal.org/tiki-index.php?page=RSS%20CloudToolbox%20Service)

If you want to process globally and for long period use
[G-POD CAT-1](http://wiki.services.eoportal.org/tiki-index.php?page=G-POD%20CAT-1%20Opportunity) (but for G-POD CAT-1 there are more stringent requirements and a limited number of projects)

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Completely processed InSAR displacement maps are not readily available, or at any rate not for large arbitrary areas. Researchers, private companies and government agencies produce them for localized areas (mines, oil fields, earthquake zones, landslides, pipeline corridors, etc.), but there is no incentive to produce them globally, and the processing times and data volumes would be prohibitive (think about it, every time a new image was acquired you could update the entire time-series, or at least the displacement in the latest period).

If you are aware of a published paper or report in the area that interests you, you might be able to obtain the displacement maps directly from the authors.

Answer (score 1):

There should be Sentinel-1 images available from all over the world. To obtain processing check for example: https://medium.com/@matusbakon/motion-in-moscow-1c98177e3c20 there's contact info for obtaining InSAR deformation maps and frequent monitoring. Sentinel-1 images are processed via SARproZ software https://www.sarproz.com there.